# How can i get the current time in C with d/m/y format?

Tags: c, date, datetime

Which function can return current datetime with *d/m/y* format in C language?

**EDIT:**

here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
int main()
{
    time_t tmp_time;
    struct tm * info;
    time ( &tmp_time );
    info = localtime ( &tmp_time ); 
    printf ( "%s", asctime (info) );
}
```

this returns to me something like that Thu Jan 26 13:08:01 2017 and i would like to return 26/01/17 or 26/01/2017

Comment: In Linux, https://linux.die.net/man/2/gettimeofday should help !!

Comment: What did a search in timing functions of C reveal so far which does not fit? Please show your effort on that topic.

Comment: @Gerhardh i edit my question to explain what exactly is my problem. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
int main ()
{
  time_t rawtime;
  struct tm * currentTime;    
  time ( &rawtime );
  currentTime = localtime ( &rawtime );
  printf ( "%d/%d/%d", currentTime->tm_mday, currentTime->tm_mon+1, currentTime->tm_year+1900);

  return 0;
}
```

Be careful, **months** are indexed since 0, and **year** is since 1900 in *tm* struct.

Comment: and if i want to have only 2 digits for year field? for example not 26/01/2017 but 17/01/17. Is it better to split 2017 string than use another solution of tm struct?

Comment: ```printf ( "%d/%d/%02d", currentTime->tm_mday, currentTime->tm_mon+1, currentTime->tm_year-100);```

Comment: usefull comment but it is better to have this value in tm_year variable and not only in printf action

Comment: no, because if you will convert ```tm``` value back to ```time_t``` using ```mktime()```, you can make some mess.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
int main()
{
    time_t t = time(0);
    if((time_t)-1 == t){
        perror(0);
        exit(1);
    }
    char buf[64];
    struct tm tdata;
    //I believe the 2 calls below should always succeed
    //in this context
    localtime_r(&t, &tdata);
    strftime(buf, sizeof(buf), "%d/%m/%y", &tdata);

    puts(buf);
}
```

The [localtime(3)](https://linux.die.net/man/3/localtime) manpage says `strftime` is the recommended way to do it, and the [strftime(3)](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strftime) manpage provides a similar example.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
time_t mytime = time(NULL);
struct tm date = *localtime(&mytime);
printf("now: %d/%d/%d\n", date.tm_mday,date.tm_mon + 1,date.tm_year +1900 );
return 0;
}
```

if you want to make it a function send the date as a parameter and return a int array holds day month and year

Comment: what if i want to take year in this format 26/01/17 and not 26/01/2017. I must split date.tm_year string?